# Probability That Each Element in a Set of Events Occurs Atleast Once in $n$ tries

Tags: probability

I was wondering about this, because I was playing a game and wanted to know how long I would need to farm (i.e. kill) certain creatures until I got 4 different items that they can drop. I needed atleast one of each, and every kill yielded  atmost 1 item, which could be one of the 4 other.

Say I have the set $S = \{A_1,A_2,\dots, A_k \}$ of items I want to collect so that $P(A_i)$ is the probability of this dropping. These numbers are constants that can be found on fanwebsites. For the sake of this problem it might be useful to assume $P(A_i)>0$ and that $\sum P(A_i)$ is not necessarily $1$.

So far I've only had about 3 weeks of probability, so if this goes above my level I'll ask my teacher.

An example of droprates (right column) for 'murlocs' in the game World of Warcraft would be:

[image]

Comment: It is possible to easily calculate the probability of a certain event $A_i$ occuring atleast once in n tries. But this would leave us hanging because this probability for one of them happening atleast once is not independent from others happening atleast once.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generalization of the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) with each coupon having a given probability $p_i$. There aren't that many explicit results for this. There's a closed form for the expectation here when you are guaranteed to have an item drop:

[Birthday paradox, coupon
collectors, caching algorithms and
self-organizing search - Flajolet et al.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fe41/6dfe577e6d77bd5c9c6af514e665f90af94a.pdf)

where Theroem 4.1 says that if $p_i$ are the probabilities of each item, then the expected time to get the full collection is:

$$E[C_m]=\int_0^\infty\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^m(1-e^{-p_it})\right)dt$$.

When you are allowed to have a null item drop, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^mp_i<1$, then there is this paper which provides some heuristic results:

[Optimization results for a generalized coupon collector problem - Anceaume, et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03878.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I think this is still a bit out of reach for me at this time. If I may ask, where did you find these resources?

Comment: I was under the assumption there would be an easier answer, because a long time ago I had seen someone post $S = 1 − 5 (1 − p)^N + 10 (1 − 2 p)^N − 10 (1 − 3 p)^N + 5 (1 − 4 p)^N − (1 − 5 p)^N$ on a forum for this type of problem. $N$ being the amount of tries, $p$ being the chance of one of the items of interest dropping (assumed to all be the same) and $S$ being the probability of it all hapening.

Comment: @JDijkstra If I read properly, Alex's answers address the time (number of tries) to get the collection, not the probability of success given a fixed number of tries.